# How to extract string in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to extract IP of source of Remote Desktop Connection using,

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`netstat -n ^| find "3389" ^| find "ESTABLISHED" /c`) DO SET /A IP=%%F

ECHO %IP%
```

But this way the IP variable contains IP along with the port `192.168.174.129:47523`.

How can I extract only the IP part?

I read about the substring functionality in batch but that requires the starting position aling with length but I can't be sure of starting position as last octet of IP might change from `129` to `29` or even `2`.

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. You should see a `delims` option, which you could assign to the `:` character.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to extract the IP out!

Comment: Without wishing to appear rude, why accept a much less efficient, or robust answer? _(when there is a significantly better one posted)_.

Comment: I didn't mean any offense, and I appreciate your answer that's why I mentioned it even in the comment. I just thought this one is easy to understand.

Comment: I wasn't offended, just surprised that an answer using twice as many `For /F` loops and twice as many `findstr.exe` commands would be chosen as a better solution. I'm not really sure how it could be less easy to understand for that reason. The only potential difficulty I can envisage would be in understanding the `findstr` match I used. If you open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should be able to work it out from the output usage information. I have however, added an overview of what it does, as additional explanation, as an edit within my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example according to my comment, of using the appropriate `delims`. It additionally uses `findstr.exe` instead of `find.exe`, in order to use a single match string, instead of performing multiple pipes to the same utility.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "IP="
For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=: " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\NETSTAT.EXE -n 2^>NUL
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R
 /C:":3389[ ][ ]*[^ ][^ ]*[ ][ ]*ESTABLISHED"') Do Set "IP=%%G"
If Not Defined IP GoTo :EOF
Echo %IP%
```

In this case, `findstr.exe` searches for, and returns, lines output from the `NETSTAT.EXE -n` command which contain the string `:3389` immediately followed by a sequence of one or more space characters, then one or more none space characters, then one or more space characters, then the case sensitive string `ESTABLISHED`.

Please note however that `ESTABLISHED` is most likely a language dependent string, so this is unlikely to work universally.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`netstat -n ^| findstr "3389" ^| findstr "ESTABLISHED"`) DO (
  for /f "delims=:" %%a in ("%%F") do set IP=%%a
)
echo %IP%
```

I replace **find** to **findstr** because **find** not search text in my machine. The second **FOR** with **delims=:** split 192.168.174.129:47523 in two parts. First part is IP address.

Comment: That's exactly what I had made out of Compo's comment